# keypress not working in ie7/8

Tags: javascript

simple question -

This will not seem to work in ie7/8. http://jsfiddle.net/XvXpE/1/

Any idea why? Or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Odd, that should work (despite e being undefined in IE). You could use the document event instead `window.onload=function(){document.onkeyup=keyUpFunc;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `document` event;

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.onkeyup=keyUp; 
}
function keyUp(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  alert(e);
};
```